# LINQ 2 OBJECTS - how to select distinct ones?

Tags: linq-to-objects, distinct

I have a collection of objects which are:
someDate
someString

I need to select objects that are different by this two fields.
And I can not select it as objects in collections - I need to create new ones.

Say:

01/01/2011 "One"

01/01/2011 "One"

01/01/2011 "One"

01/01/2011 "Two"

(I need to note - this four are different to each other)

And I need to get:

01/01/2011 "One"

01/01/2011 "Two"

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, particularly: "And I can not select it as objects in collections - I need to create new ones."

Answer (score 5):

Your question is fairly unclear, but it sounds like you *either* just need to use `Distinct` after a projection:

```
var distinctDatesAndNames = items.Select(x => new { x.Date, x.Name })
                                 .Distinct();
```

*or* you need to use something like `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var distinctItems = items.DistinctBy(x => new { x.Date, x.Name });
```

It would *really* help if you could clarify your question though.

Comment: After projection? My main problem is that I thought that "new" keyword will create an instance of anonymous object for EVERY object in incoming collection. How can Distinct() determine - which are different and which are not?

Comment: @Monochromie: Yes, it will create a new instance for each object - but then `Distinct` will use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to find equal ones.